# OpenMP collapse giving wrong result

Tags: c++, openmp

I am new to c++ and i am testing how to use OpenMP for parallelisation with multiple for loops, I have noticed that after trying 5 loops with collapse, i end up with the number 1,410,065,408

```cpp
void doStuff() {
    long long loop = 0;
    int a = 100;
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:loop) collapse(5)
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < a; k++) {
                for (int l = 0; l < a; l++) {
                    for (int m = 0; m < a; m++) {
                        loop++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
    std::cout << loop << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    doStuff(); 
    return 0;
}
```

if i remove `collapse(5)` or set it to less than or equal to 4 (which is slower), it gives the desired result of 10,000,000,000. What is happening and can i fix it?

Comment: Side note: Look at the compiler being a complete nerd and optimizing out all of the loops: https://godbolt.org/z/WaedM4zWY

Comment: This is an overflow. Use `long long` for the variables of the loop and it should fix the problem. OpenMP cannot know that it need to use a bigger type because of the collapse. AFAIK, it takes the type of the first variable (`i`) as the reference type for the collapse. An `int` cannot contains numbers bigger than ~2.147e9 (while it should iterate up to 10e9 with a full collapse).

Comment: Proof of the above explanation : https://godbolt.org/z/zT7e7Y8Th (while it results in [this](https://godbolt.org/z/WbjETG9sz) initially)

Comment: I seriously doubt that the code is slower with `collapse(4)` compared to `collapse(5)`.